# How can I simulate a press of the home button in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to simulate the press of the home button to exit the application with the animation. I think I can do this with the UIATarget class, but I don't know what framework it's in so I can import it. How do I simulate the press of a home button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For debug purpose you can try:

```
 exit(0);
```

or

```
 [[NSThread mainThread] exit];
```

But, on the iPhone there is no concept of quitting an app. The only action that should cause an app to quit is touching the Home button on the phone, and that's not something developers have access to.

According to Apple, your app should not terminate on its own. Since the user did not hit the Home button, any return to the Home screen gives the user the impression that your app crashed. This is confusing, non-standard behavior and **should be avoided**.

You should read the Technical Q&A about this topics [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html)

Comment: I know I can do `exit(0)`, but I kinda want to close it with animation. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: If Apple will reject such application, I'm pretty sure that having an animation will make no difference. Better take as it's not possible.

Comment: The app is not actually going to the App store. Probably cydia/open source

Comment: If this is a Cydia app, you might get a good lead from looking into the Activator API. Activator can do plenty of stuff like that.